# one function not running with jQuery infinite carousel build

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so i have tried making myself an infinite carousel using html, css & jQuery and everything is working apart from the back button will not loop, i've spent quite a while doing this now and i'm wondering if anyone has any insight? http://jsfiddle.net/e2SKk/ is where you can see the code! i'm only really doing this because i thought it would give me a chance to learn a lot more, but any criticisms of code layout or technique would be helpful!

specifically its this code thats seems not to work

```
else if(loopPrev==true){
            sliderActive=true
            $('.item-holder').css({
                'left':clonePos
            });
            $('.item-holder').animate({
                'left':holderPos+$('.slider').width()+'px'
            },function(){
                sliderActive=false;
            });
        };
```

that is only a snippet btw and won't make much sense without the rest!

Comment: if you cant help at least check it out its pretty cool for a beginner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is cool to write short scripts.
Your slider code in short:

```
var width = $('.slider').width();
$('.item').css({width:width});
var $holder = $('.item-holder').css({left:-width}).prepend($('.item:last'));

$('.prev').click(function(){
    $holder.not(':animated').css({left:-2*width}).prepend($('.item:last')).animate({left:-width});
});
$('.next').click(function(){
    $holder.not(':animated').css({left:0}).append($('.item:first')).animate({left:-width});
});
```

​
That's the **complete** code.

See this in action on http://jsfiddle.net/creativecouple/YPU2d/

Comment: whaaat!? how did you make it into only three functions? and does that mean the variable '$holder' is actually an object? and also how does .not(':animated') work? thank you although it doesn't completely make sense to me i am now fuelled to code everything in such short amount! @peter

Comment: i fail to see how this qualifies as a decent answer, but at least you learned something new egg!  welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: $holder is just a variable for a 'real' jQuery object.
.not(':animated') just ignores any action when the slider currently moves. ".not()" is a negative filter, and ":animated" is a jQuery selector for animated elements.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty cool little slider you have going here!  You say you are a beginner?  I'd say you've picked up on jQuery quite well!  Also before I forget, addressing your comment: if you post something on stackoverflow...it WILL be viewed, likely by many people :).  It's rare to come here and receive no help (albeit you may not always get an answer).

Fortunately for you, I've found your problem!  It's right here:

```
else if(loopPrev==true){
    sliderActive=true
    $('.item-holder').css({
        'left':clonePos
    });
    $('.item-holder').animate({
        'left':holderPos+$('.slider').width()+'px'
    },function(){
        sliderActive=false;
    });
};
```

You are checking whether or not to loop, setting the slider to active, setting the next slide to the last slide in the index (and subsequently pushing it to that at the same time), then you animate as you normally would.  This results in two movements: first to the back of the index, then to  the value of holderPos+$('.slider').width()+'px'...hence your strange behaviour.  This should help:

```
 else if(loopPrev==true){
     sliderActive=true;
     $('.item-holder').animate({
         'left':"-1800px"
     }, function(){ 
         sliderActive=false; 
     })
 };
```

The value "-1800px" is just the last slide in your buffer that I precalculated...you should be able to replace it with your clonePos variable without trouble.

*EDIT: You should also change your variable clonePos to look like this:

```
var clonePos = '-'+($('.item').index()-1)*($('.slider').width());
```

It will eliminate a bug when you swap between the last slide in the index and the first slide (a "smooth transition" if you will).

**

### Part II

**

In order to achieve the illusion of infinite scrollability you will need to embed a callback "push back" function inside the "left pressed" animation call.  It's late here so I haven't tested the code I am about to write but I'm fairly confident it will work for you.

```
else if(loopPrev==true){
 sliderActive=true;
 $('.item-holder').animate({
     'left':clonePos
 }, function(){
     $(this).css('left':holderPos+$('.slider').width()+'px');
     sliderActive=false; 
 })
};
```

If you take a look this isn't much different from the original answer I offered.  All we have done is take the callback function for animate, and added a call to slip the position to the original index position.  Again, untested, but the idea is that .animate() will slide to the clone, once that is done your callback will swap the clone with the original, and then deactivate the slider.

You weren't very far off!  Here's a semantic rule of the animate function (to attempt to help your understanding of the way a callback works):

```
animate( params, [duration], [easing], [callback] )
```

- params is our left call (to the cloned slide in this case)
- duration is ignored here
- easing is ignored here
- callback is our function() call that does our little david copperfield swap

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much! but the problem is i'm trying to make it infinite, so i have cloned the first item and added it to the end of the list, so when on the actual first item, i want it to "css" to the last item(the first item cloned" and then go left, to the actual last item"item-four", i'm sorry if that doesn't make any sense i find it difficult to explain! but thanks ever so much for responding!!

Comment: what you want is called a callback.  more specifically a callback animation.  its basicly just calling a function as a part of another functions final parameter (if allowed).  this callback function is called only after the initial function is completed.  i'll edit the top answer with an example